# Why does changing Component props in App.js doesn't automatically refreshes it in browser when props are used in state of class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started to learn React and want to understand the difference in props and state behavior. I have two files App.js and Counter.js.

App.js:

```
import Counter from './Counter'

function App() {
  return (
    <Counter initialCount={2} />
  )
}

export default App;
```

And Counter.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            count: props.initialCount
        }
    }

    render() {
            return (
                    <div>
                    <button>-</button>
                    <span>{ this.state.count }</span>
                    <button>+</button>
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

When  I change `initialCount` in App.js and save file, it only changes in browser automatically if I have `{ this.props.initialCount }` in `<span></span>`.

If I have `{ this.state.count }` between spans (as in the code above), and try to change `initialCount` in App.js and hit save, then the value in  doesn't change in browser. If I refresh the browser or change something in Counter.js after that and hit save (even adding simple space anywhere), then it updates the value without me having to refresh the browser.

I use Chrome and ReactDeveloperTools. From Components tab I can see that after I hit save in App.js, it changes props to the new value, but state is still the same.

It seems that constructor only called once. But I still don't understand this behavior.

Comment: I can't reproduce that with the code you're showing. This seems to work perfectly fine. https://codepen.io/pomax-the-scripter/pen/VwMrXJZ

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's a file watch / browserSynch issue . Not sure how you code ever repro that in codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component's constructor is only called once, when component is created. So when you for example change initialCount programmatically, Counter's constructor would not be called again.

This is a feature of Hot Reloading which does not recreate Counter component when you change props in App, but behaves as props of Counter component are changed programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are confusing two different things. One thing is a rerender on the change of data in React (say counter value changes onClick event) and the other is a manual change of hardcoded data in the application.

You seem to be describing a forced rerender with a change in your source code. It is most likely connected with the watcher tool that is set up by a tool that manages automatic updates during the development on a local server (Webpack / Create React App setup most likely). I tried to simulate in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-vwqf5?file=/App.jsx) but could not, as the counter value is always refreshed despite using state or props.

Also, FYI, beware of setting state with props. You can read this short [post](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e) about it.

Comment: I just go through the course called "Web Dev Simplified - Learn React Today". And this is what the guy shows during explaining the class components. Thank you for your insights. I will check all the links.